# Linear Systems ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that the square matrix $A$ has a negative eigenvalue. Show that the linear system $x' = Ax$ has at least one nontrivial solution $x(t)$ that satisfies $$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $(\lambda ,v)$ be an eigenpair of $A_{n\times n}$ and consider the function $x\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^{n\times 1}, t\mapsto e^{\lambda t}v$.

Comment: There is a $t$ missing, it should be $e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: @Mercy Yes, thank you.